# Extract first few path as variable within nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

I want to dynamically build proxy pass based on the path parameters but I'm having hard time breaking each path into the arguments.

```
location ~ ^/proxy/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)(/.*)*$ {
  resolver 127.0.0.1;
  proxy_pass $1.$2.$3.host.com;
}
```

```
# below will have the host name of `a/b/c/d/e.f.g.host.com`
# where as I want to navigate to `a.b.c.host.com`
curl 127.0.0.1/proxy/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
```

I'm bit confused about this issue.
Also, doing names variable didn't help either.
And depth of my path is variable so all I want is first 3 path as arguments.

How can I Extract each of the first 3 path as variables within nginx?

Comment: Use `([^/]*)` instead of `(.*)`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!!  I swear I have tried it but I guess I didn't.  Just to be clear actual line ended up being `location ~ ^/proxy/([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/(.*)$ {`.  I'm bit confused about when does nginx escapes certain chars and when it doesn't